# test convergence of improper integrals 4

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Test the convergence of improper integrals :

$$\int_1^2{\sqrt x\over \log x}dx$$

I basically have no idea how to approach a problem in which log appears. Need some hint on solving this type of problems.

Comment: The problematic point here is the zero of $\log$ in $1$. How does $\log$ behave near $1$, and how $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand that the problem lies at $x=1$ as $log1=0$ so how do i proceed with the solution ? i practical test, wasn't able to go too far

Comment: @Aman have a look at the answer below.

Comment: How does $\log$ behave around $1$? A Taylor expansion might prove helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^1 dx \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\log{(1+x)}}$$

Now, for the bottom limit of the integral, note that

$$\log{(1+\epsilon)} \sim \epsilon$$

so that, near this limit, the integrand behaves as $1/\epsilon$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, or as $1/x$ as $x \to 0$.  This represents a non-integrable singularity (the integral would behave as $\log{\epsilon}$ near this limit), and therefore the integral diverges.

Comment: don't we apply the limits after integral ?

Comment: Yes, but in considering the convergence of the integral, one must investigate the behavior of the integrand.  For integrands that do not change sign (which you have here), convergence is determined by comparison with $x^{a}$ near an integration limit or singular point in the integration region; if $a>-1$, then the integrand converges, otherwise it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $I(\delta)=\displaystyle\int_{1+ \delta}^2{\sqrt x\over \log x}dx$

$$I(\delta) \ge \displaystyle\int_{1+ \delta}^2{1\over \log x} \geq \displaystyle\int_{1+ \delta}^2{1\over x-1}=-\log\delta$$

As, $\log x \le x-1 $ for $x\ge 1$.

Letting $\delta \to 0$ you can have that your integral diverges, as $I(\delta)$ is continuousin $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} (x-1) \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln x} = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{\sqrt{x} + (x-1) \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1 $$

The integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{x-1}$ near $x=1$ and thus $ \displaystyle\int_1^2{\sqrt x\over \log x}dx$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

First make the change of variables $\ln(x)=u$

$$\int_1^2{\sqrt x\over \log x}dx =\int _{0}^{\ln  \left( 2 \right) }\!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{3/2\,u}}}{u}}{du}.$$

Now, you can see that the integrand behaves as

$$ {\frac {{{\rm e}^{3/2\,u}}}{u}}\sim _{u\to 0} \frac{1}{u} $$

which is not integrable on the given interval.