# Show that $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{\ln x}dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus

I need to show that the integral

$$ \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{\ln x} dx $$

diverges.

I know that for $x \in (1,2]$ we have $ x-1 \geq \ln x$ , which  implies $ \frac{1}{x-1} \leq \frac{1}{\ln x}$. In this, since the function that i used and the lgarithm are not defined for $x=1$, i had to take of $1$ from the interval. It is only one point, I know it shouldn't make difference in my integral result. But, doing the exercise like that is correct and rigorous?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct, the single point does not make a difference, because the (improper) integral is *defined* as $$\lim_{\eta \to 1}\int_\eta^2 \frac1{\ln x}dx$$and a limit doesn't care about the final point.

Comment: Thank you! You sre the only one who really answered what I was looking for.

Comment: You're very welcome. ---

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following fact to find out if the improper integral diverges or not. In fact this is base of using the Comparison test. Also we see that $f(1)=\ln(1)=0$ :

> Let $\lim_{n\to a^+}~(x-a)^pf(x)=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p\ge1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ diverges.

Now check $\lim_{n\to 1^+}~(x-a)^1\frac{1}{\ln(x)}=A$.

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=e^u$ then $dx= e^u du$ and then
$$\int_1^2 \frac{dx}{\ln x}=\int_0^{\ln 2}\frac{e^u}{u}du$$
and then the integral is divergent since
$$\frac{e^u}{u}\sim_0 \frac{1}{u}$$
and the integral 
$$\int_0^{\ln 2} \frac{du}{u}$$
is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_1^2 {1\over x-1}\,dx\le\int_1^2 {1\over \ln x}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\int_1^2 {1\over x-1}\,dx=\lim_{b\to 1^+}\int_b^2 {1\over x-1}\,dx=\lim_{b\to 1^+}\ln|x-1|{\Large|}_{b}^2=\lim_{b\to 1^+}(\ln 1-\ln |b-1|)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** use the change of variables $\ln x = u$ and things will be clear. See [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452803/test-convergence-of-improper-integrals-4) for more details.