# How many ways can you show that $ \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

How many ways can you show that this integral is divergent? $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{(1-x)^2} \,dx$

The only way I was able to show this was using a hint which was given to me that I don't think I could've come up with. That hint was to observe that $\large \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{1-x}$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and then use substitution followed by the $p$-test for $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{M}{1-x}$, where $M$ is the upper bound.

Any tips or new skills would be appreciated!

Someone mentioned comparing $\sin(\pi x)$ to $\pi x (1-x)$ though I can't seems to figure this out either (even with the help of the series expansion).

Comment: Substitute $t = 1-x$. Since $\sin (\pi -z) = \sin z$, you get $$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (\pi t)}{t^2}\,dt.$$

Answer (score 3):

Recalling the Taylor series of $\sin(\pi x)$ at the point $x=1$

> $$ \sin(\pi x) = -\pi \, \left( x-1 \right) + \frac{\pi^3}{3!}\left( x-1 \right) ^{3}-\dots \implies \sin(\pi x)\sim  -\pi \, \left( x-1 \right)$$

which implies the integrand behaves like

> $$ \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x-1)^2} \sim \frac{-\pi(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}= \frac{-\pi}{x-1} $$

Now, I think you can finish the problem. See my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452803/test-convergence-of-improper-integrals-4).

Comment: The second term of the expansion of $\sin(\pi x)$ is wrong.

Comment: @Did: It is a typo. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a little artificial the way it is formulated.  It is more convenient to make a change of variables $t=1-x$ and then you get a similar integral with a singularity at the origin.  Your integral converges if and only if the new one does, therefore it is sufficient to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin t}{t^2}$ diverges.  This follows by comparing $\sin t$ to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Do the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$; use periodicity of $\sin$; do a Taylor expansion of $\sin$; observe that $\int_0 \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one proof of the theorem, it follows that there is a countably infinite number of other proofs. I believe this still holds if you exclude proofs that have useless deductions (to eliminate redundancy).